# Hooking into message pump of STA Apartment COM object activated in DllHost by DllSurrogate

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, com

I have a fairly complex requirement. My STA COM object is implemented in a DLL (can't move it to out-of-process EXE). By the means of `DllSurrogate` I am hosting my object in a `dllhost.exe` process. My object has an UI attached to it (a plain modeless dialog) but I need the `PreTranslateAccelerator` mechanism in order for some shortcuts to work, etc. Since COM activates my object and hosts it in the default `dllhost.com`, I am obviously not controlling the message pump.

Is there still a way to pre-translate messages in this scenario? I doubt COM has foreseen such a specific scenario but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: ActiveX was designed to run in-process, depending on the ActiveX host to pump.  So no, a surrogate is out.  You'll have to rebuild to target x64.

Comment: It's incredible how one gets ideas while writing elaborate questions on SO. I have tried a GetMessage hook and it almost works. If I understand you correctly you are suggesting that this is not possible (by conventional means). Though I am not sure what x64 has to do with this. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Why else would you use a surrogate?

Comment: I need a surrogate so I can have one master shared object among many others living in many different processes. It's a complex scenario but it works perfectly across systems (from XP onwards). I am constrained by a single DLL.

Comment: @wpfwannabe So why isn't this just implemented as a LocalServer? If you played by all the rules of COM within your existing code, I would think the translation would be straight-forward. If not.... Do you simply not "own" the DLL, but tooled the registration to use the surrogate model instead of in-proc?

Comment: @WhozCraig: As I just said, I needed to pack everything in a single DLL. DllSurrogate worked perfectly until I came across the need of PreTranslateMessage. I guess I could spin a worker UI thread to host the UI but that sounds like more marshalling overhead for all the connected processes (as UI does most of the work).

Comment: It sounds like you are using a surrogate to solve what the Running Object Table (ROT) was designed for (see [`GetRunningObjectTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684004.aspx) for additional information). It allows you to register COM objects to be accessible from arbitrary clients running on the same workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I needed to pack everything in a single DLL.

In which case, `DllSurrogate` is not the only way of doing this. There's also `Rundll32`:

[INFO: Windows Rundll and Rundll32 Interface](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787)

This would allow you to run your own message loop inside the DLL's `EntryPoint` and have complete control over message processing, including `PreTranslateMessage`. You can copy the message loop logic from an ATL EXE server.

Bear in mind, there's still 32-bit and 64-bit version of "RunDll32.exe" in every 64-bit Windows OS. Use the one which matches the bit-ness of your DLL.

Comment: I don't think `rundll` can help me. I don't see how. But I've ended up solving the problem by creating a custom factory which created my object on a distinct UI thread. The clients talk to the STA object on a non-main UI thread. As this is my own thread, I control the message loop and everything. Works like a charm! I accepted your answer because of the support even though you I found the answer for myself. Of course, all the comments here helped.

Comment: @wpfwannabe, it sounds like an interesting solution, feel free to post your own answer. As to rundll32, you'd register it as your EXE server, then do `CoRegisterClassObject` and run the message loop.

Comment: ...and so I did. Comments are welcome. As for `rundll32`... obviously I can't register a DLL as an EXE server, right?

Comment: @wpfwannabe, in fact you can. You can specify `rundll32.exe` with custom command line (and thus, a custom entry point) for `LocalServer32` registry value.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay here it is. I hope I didn't leave out anything important. Basically, I have created a custom `CMyComCreator` instead of the default one. Instead of just creating a COM object and returning an interface pointer, I spin a worker `UiThread`. I use `MyData` structure to pass data across threads. Once the worker thread has finished setting up, I use the `CComGITPtr` to transfer the marshalled interface pointer from the `UiThread` back to the main. The consumers (out-of-process) end up with interface pointers that talk directly to the `UiThread` bypassing the main thread. You may think of `CMyDialog` as a modeless dialog which sends a `PostQuitMessage` on destruction to terminate the message loop. That's all. May look cumbersome but it works good.

```
struct MyData
{
    ATL::CComGITPtr<IUnknown> Unk;
    ATL::CEvent Event;
    HRESULT hr;

    MyData() : hr(E_OUTOFMEMORY), Event(FALSE, FALSE) { }
};

static CMessageLoop * MessageLoop;

class CMyComCreator
{
public:
    static HRESULT WINAPI CreateInstance(
        _In_opt_ void* pv,
        _In_ REFIID riid,
        _COM_Outptr_ LPVOID* ppv)
    {
        ATLASSERT(ppv != NULL);
        if (ppv == NULL)
            return E_POINTER;
        *ppv = NULL;

        HRESULT hRes = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
        MyData* data = NULL;

        ATLPREFAST_SUPPRESS(6014 28197)
            /* prefast noise VSW 489981 */
            ATLTRY(data = _ATL_NEW MyData)
        ATLPREFAST_UNSUPPRESS()

        if (data != NULL)
        {
            HANDLE thread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, UiThread, (void *)data, 0, NULL);

            if (thread)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(data->Event, INFINITE);
                CloseHandle(thread);

                hRes = data->hr;

                if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
                {
                    ATL::CComPtr<IUnknown> unk;

                    hRes = data->Unk.CopyTo(&unk);

                    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
                    {
                        hRes = unk->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
                    }
                }
            }

            delete data;
        }
        return hRes;
    }
};

typedef CMyComCreator _CreatorClass;

static unsigned __stdcall UiThread(void * param)
{
    CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    MyData * data = (MyData *)param;

    ATL::CComObject<CMyDialog> * bb;
    data->hr = ATL::CComObject<CMyDialog>::CreateInstance(&bb);

    ATL::CComPtr<IUnknown> unk((IDispatch *) bb);

    data->Unk = unk;
    unk.Release();
    data->Event.Set();

    if (SUCCEEDED(data->hr))
    {
        CMessageLoop theLoop;
        MessageLoop = &theLoop;
        int nRet = theLoop.Run();
        MessageLoop = NULL;
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can see the concept, but you really should be marshaling `data->Unk` from the `UiThread` thread to the thread on which `CreateInstance` was invoked. You can use `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` for that. Otherwise, you're violating COM apartment rules.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing, aren't I? Instead of `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` I am using `CComGITPtr`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. Nothing's wrong with that, you can do it via GIT, too.